# PHP reading file - not finiding it

Tags: php, file-read

I am trying to read a text file, the filename is based on a variable.

```
<?php
$todaydate = date("Y-m-d");
$lines = file("/news/$todaydate.txt");
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
}
?>
```

This is the error I get:

```
PHP Warning:  file(/news/2020-08-04.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dev/proj1/readinsert.php on line 3
```

I am 100% sure that the file exists. :)
What basic error am I making?

Comment: With the path `/news`, are you sure this directory is off the root of your filesystem and not your web application?

Comment: Doh. It is the web application. Ashamed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the / at the beginning of the path and use relative paths

Also, try to get more info using getcwd and file_exists